# Listas dobles c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Nodo{
    int nro;
    Nodo *ant;
    Nodo *sgt;

};

void insertarListaFinal(Nodo *&lista, int valor){

    Nodo *q= new Nodo();
    Nodo *t;
    q->nro=valor;
    q->ant=NULL;
    q->sgt=NULL;

    if(lista==NULL){
        lista=q;

    }else{
        t=lista;
        while(t->sgt!=NULL){
            t=t->sgt;
        }
        t->sgt=q;
        q->ant=t;
    }

}


void insertarElementoDespues(Nodo *&lista,int valorBus, int valorIns){

    Nodo *q= new Nodo();
    q->ant=NULL;
    q->sgt=NULL;
    q->nro=valorIns;

    Nodo *p,*a;
    p=lista;

    if(lista!=NULL){
        while(p!=NULL){
            if(p->nro==valorBus){
                a=p->sgt;
                if(p->sgt!=NULL){
                    a->ant=q;
                    p->sgt=a;
                }
                q->ant=p;
                p->sgt=q;
            }
        }
        p=p->sgt;
        }else{
            lista=q;
    }

}
void mostrarListaDoble(Nodo *&lista){

    Nodo *t=lista;
    while(t!=NULL){
        cout<<t->nro<<endl;
        t=t->sgt;
    }

}



int main (){

    Nodo *lista=NULL;

    int n,numero,v1,v2;

    cout<<"Ingrese Cantidad De Numero :";
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"Numero "<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>numero;
        insertarListaFinal(lista,numero);
    }

    cout<<"-------------------"<<endl;
    mostrarListaDoble(lista);


    cout<<"Ingrese Valor A Buscar :";
    cin>>v1;
    cout<<"Digite Valor A Insertar :";
    cin>>v2;
    insertarElementoDespues(lista,v1,v2);
    mostrarListaDoble(lista);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

No me muestra la lista ; con el nuevo elemento que ingrese el problema es aquí--

```
---> 
cout<<"Ingrese Valor A Buscar :";
    cin>>v1;
    cout<<"Digite Valor A Insertar :";
    cin>>v2;
    insertarElementoDespues(lista,v1,v2);
    mostrarListaDoble(lista);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tene en cuenta que un monton de codigo es dificil de seguir y entender. Por favor trata de aclarar tu problema especifico y donde ocurre

Answer (score 1):

#### Los Nodos no son Listas.

Este es un error recurrente en StackOverflow en Español que genera mucha confusión.

En el código que has facilitado estás pasando (`Nodo *&`) una referencia a puntero a `Nodo` con el nombre de `lista`. Y eso es tan erróneo como decir que un escalón es una escalera, sinceramente ¿Te parecen lo mismo?:

[image]
[image]

#### La nomenclatura es importante.

Además de la incorrecta nomenclatura de nodos y listas, el resto de tus variables son confusas y propensas a errores (como el error que ha encontrado [Zeugirdor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/203334/2742)). Evita usar variables cuyo nombre sea una letra y usa nombres cuyo significado sea claro en una primera lectura, nombres como `q`, `p`, `t`, `n`, `v1` o `v2` no aportan ninguna información de su cometido ni su intencionalidad, los nombres como `nro`, `sgt` y `ant` son ligeramente más explicativos pero aún así confusos cuando falta contexto.

#### Tu pregunta es sobre C++.

El lenguaje C++ es multiparadigma, así que a priori no estás limitado a un paradigma concreto; pero uno de los puntos fuertes del lenguaje es su soporte a la [programación orientada a objetos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos) así que te aconsejo que realmente crees un objeto lista.

#### Propuesta.

Teniendo en cuenta todo lo anterior, tu código podría tener este aspecto:

```
class Lista // Un objeto lista, nombre auto-explicativo.
{
    struct Nodo
    {
        // Nombres auto-explicativos, valores por defecto.
        int numero      {0};
        Nodo *anterior  {nullptr};
        Nodo *siguiente {nullptr};
    };

    Nodo *raiz {nullptr}; // Nombre auto-explicativo, valor por defecto. 
public:
    void insertarFinal(int valor);
};
```

La clase `Lista` dispone de una clase interna en la zona privada que es el `Nodo`; esta clase privada es inaccesible desde fuera favoreciendo el [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)): la propia clase gestiona sus nodos, desde fuera de la lista no hay motivos para trabajar con nodos.

Con este código, la implementación de `insertarFinal` podría parecerse a:

```
void insertarFinal(int valor)
{
    if (raiz) // Si hay datos
    {
        Nodo *ultimo = raiz;
        // Avanzamos hasta dar con el último nodo, que será aquel
        // que no tenga siguiente. Nótese el fin de instrucción -----> v
        for (; ultimo && ultimo->siguiente; ultimo = ultimo->siguiente);

        // El siguiente del nuevo Nodo obtiene nullptr por defecto
        // El anterior del nuevo Nodo obtiene el valor de ultimo al construirse
        ultimo->siguiente = new Nodo{valor, ultimo};
    }
    else // Si no hay datos
    {
        // El anterior y siguiente del nuevo Nodo obtienen nullptr por defecto
        raiz = new Nodo{valor};
    }
}
```

Esta lista podría usarse así:

```
Lista l;
l.insertarFinal(3);
l.insertarFinal(2);
l.insertarFinal(1);

std::cout << l; // Muestra 321
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [<kbd>Wandbox</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QJQzMyeAmLxw7rUV).

Answer (score 0):

Este es tu código "corregido":

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Nodo{
    int nro;
    Nodo *ant;
    Nodo *sgt;

};

void insertarListaFinal(Nodo *lista, int valor){

    Nodo *q= new Nodo;
    Nodo *t;
    q->nro=valor;
    q->ant=NULL;
    q->sgt=NULL;

    if(lista==NULL){
        lista=q;

    }else{
        t=lista;
        while(t->sgt!=NULL){
            t=t->sgt;
        }
        t->sgt=q;
        q->ant=t;
    }

}


void insertarElementoDespues(Nodo *lista,int valorBus, int valorIns){
    Nodo *q= new Nodo;
    q->ant=NULL;
    q->sgt=NULL;
    q->nro=valorIns;

    if(lista!=NULL){
        Nodo *p,*a;
        p=lista;
        while(p!=NULL){
            if(p->nro==valorBus){
                a=p->sgt;
                if(p->sgt!=NULL){
                    a->ant=q;
                    q->sgt=a;
                }
                q->ant=p;
                p->sgt=q;
            }
            p=p->sgt;
        }
    }
    else{
        lista=q;
    }
}

void mostrarListaDoble(Nodo *lista){

    Nodo *t=lista;
    while(t!=NULL){
        cout<<t->nro<<endl;
        t=t->sgt;
    }

}



int main (){

    Nodo *lista=new Nodo;

    int n,numero,v1,v2;

    cout<<"Ingrese Cantidad De Numero :";
    cin>>n;
    if(n>0){
        cout<<"Numero "<<1<<endl;
        cin>>numero;
        lista->nro=numero;
        lista->ant=NULL;
        lista->sgt=NULL;

        if(n>1){
            for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
                cout<<"Numero "<<i+1<<endl;
                cin>>numero;
                insertarListaFinal(lista,numero);
            }
        }
        cout<<"-------------------"<<endl;
        mostrarListaDoble(lista);


        cout<<"Ingrese Valor A Buscar :";
        cin>>v1;
        cout<<"Digite Valor A Insertar :";
        cin>>v2;
        insertarElementoDespues(lista,v1,v2);
        mostrarListaDoble(lista);

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Qué hice?**

Bien, pues, primero lo que hago es reservar la memoria para lista ya creando el primer nodo, la "cabeza", si el usuario ingresa una `n` mayor o igual a 1, obligatoriamente asigno los vaores de la cabeza en main y luego paso al `for` de ser mayor a 1.

Luego también te arreglé un problema en `insertarElementoDespues` ya que habías puesto:

```
        if(p->sgt!=NULL){
            a->ant=q;
            p->sgt=a;
        }
```

Y en realidad es:

```
        if(p->sgt!=NULL){
            a->ant=q;
            q->sgt=a;
        }
```

Puesto que el puntero siguiente de `p` es `a`, y como que si le asignas nuevamente a no tiene sentido, tienes que asignar que el puntero siguiente de `q` es `a`, no de `p`.

También cambié todos los `*&` por directamente `*`, ya que estás trabajando con punteros y cambié los `Nodo();` por `Nodo` ya que lo que haces es crear una estructura de tipo `Nodo` no es una función `Nodo`.

Añadí también unas comprobaciones, como que no se ejecute si n es 0 o cosas así, te invito a revisarlo para que veas lo que cambié y si tienes dudas sobre alguna parte, pregúntame!

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Muchas gracias !!!

Comment: @user8984445 si esta respuesta fue la solución a tu problema, porfavor tildala como correcta!

Comment: Mucho cuidado, tu versión de `insertarListaFinal` recibe un puntero a nodo (`Nodo*`) y la de @user8984445 recibe una referencia a puntero a nodo (`Nodo*&`) en tu versión estás modificando una **copia** del puntero, con lo que pueden surgir fallos en tiempo de ejecución.